# Как изменить скрипт, чтобы анимация не останавливалась, а бесконечно повторялась?

Tags: jquery

На страницах stackoverflow в одном из ответов был найден данный скрипт - смена фоновых изображений `background-image` у указанного `div`. Работает в целом как мне требуется под определенную задачу, но проблема в том, что скрипт после одного прохода останавливается. Подскажите пожалуйста, как изменить скрипт, чтобы он бесконечно повторял смену картинок?

```js
var editBg = function(content__bg) {
  var contents__bg = $('.content').find('.content__bg');
  contents__bg.animate({opacity: 'hide'}, 500);
  setTimeout(function() {
    contents__bg.remove();
  }, 500);
  $('.content').prepend($('<div class="content__bg '+content__bg+'"></div>'));
};
$(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    editBg('content__bg_img--1');
  }, 3000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    editBg('content__bg_img--2');
  }, 6000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    editBg('content__bg_img--3');
  }, 9000);
});
```

```css
.content {
  position: relative;
  width: 220px;
  height: 160px;
}
.content__bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.content__bg_img--0 {background-image: url('http://wp.widewallpapers.ru/2k/nature/forest/1920x1200/forest-wallpaper-1920x1200-004.jpg')}
.content__bg_img--1 {background-image: url('http://anywalls.com/pic/201210/1366x768/anywalls.com-14971.jpg')}
.content__bg_img--2 {background-image: url('http://www.1366x768.ru/nature/29/park-wallpaper-1366x768.jpg')}
.content__bg_img--3 {background-image: url('http://wp.widewallpapers.ru/2k/nature/forest/1920x1080/forest-wallpaper-1920x1080-003.jpg')}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="content__bg content__bg_img--0"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: а можно ссылку на тот вопрос, где было приведено данное решение? Выглядит все это, откровенно говоря, крайне сомнительно.

Comment: @MedvedevDev https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/614707/232533

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так можно сделать, в место `timeout` поставить `setInterval`.

```js
let next_item = 1;
var editBg = function() {
  if(next_item > 3){
    next_item = 0;
  }
  var contents__bg = $('.content').find('.content__bg');
  contents__bg.animate({opacity: 'hide'}, 500);
  setTimeout(function() {
    contents__bg.remove();
  }, 500);
  $('.content').prepend($('<div class="content__bg content__bg_img--'+next_item+'"></div>'));
  next_item++;
};
$(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    editBg();
  }, 3000);
});
```

```css
content {
  position: relative;
  width: 220px;
  height: 160px;
}
.content__bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.content__bg_img--0 {
  background-image: url('http://wp.widewallpapers.ru/2k/nature/forest/1920x1200/forest-wallpaper-1920x1200-004.jpg');
}
.content__bg_img--1 {
  background-image: url('http://anywalls.com/pic/201210/1366x768/anywalls.com-14971.jpg');
}
.content__bg_img--2 {
  background-image: url('http://www.1366x768.ru/nature/29/park-wallpaper-1366x768.jpg');
}
.content__bg_img--3 {
  background-image: url('http://wp.widewallpapers.ru/2k/nature/forest/1920x1080/forest-wallpaper-1920x1080-003.jpg');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="content__bg content__bg_img--0"></div>
</div>
```

Вот второй вариант с рандомным показом изображений.

```js
let next_item = 1;
function randomInteger(min, max) {
  var rand = min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1)
  rand = Math.round(rand);
  return rand;
}

var editBg = function() {
  if(next_item > 3){
    next_item = 0;
  }
  var contents__bg = $('.content').find('.content__bg');
  contents__bg.animate({opacity: 'hide'}, 500);
  setTimeout(function() {
    contents__bg.remove();
  }, 500);
  $('.content').prepend($('<div class="content__bg content__bg_img--'+next_item+'"></div>'));
  next_item++;
};
$(function() {
  var first_item = randomInteger(0, 3);
  $('.content').prepend($('<div class="content__bg content__bg_img--'+first_item+'"></div>'));
  next_item = first_item + 1;
  setInterval(function() {
    editBg();
  }, 3000);
});
```

```css
content {
  position: relative;
  width: 220px;
  height: 160px;
}
.content__bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.content__bg_img--0 {
  background-image: url('http://wp.widewallpapers.ru/2k/nature/forest/1920x1200/forest-wallpaper-1920x1200-004.jpg');
}
.content__bg_img--1 {
  background-image: url('http://anywalls.com/pic/201210/1366x768/anywalls.com-14971.jpg');
}
.content__bg_img--2 {
  background-image: url('http://www.1366x768.ru/nature/29/park-wallpaper-1366x768.jpg');
}
.content__bg_img--3 {
  background-image: url('http://wp.widewallpapers.ru/2k/nature/forest/1920x1080/forest-wallpaper-1920x1080-003.jpg');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  
</div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Все работает как и требуется, а не подскажите возможно ли добавить такую функцию, чтобы при каждой загрузке/обновлении страницы анимация начиналась со случайного/рандомного изображения?

Comment: @Slava Все можно, но если это не срочно то давайте завтра напишите мне я дам еще ответ с этой функцией.

Comment: Спасибо за добавленную рандомную функцию! Работает как и требуется, получилось очень легкое и изящное решение!!

Comment: @Slava Не за что.

Answer (score 1):

Если вам наплевать на древние браузеры, то советую максимально использовать CSS свойство `transition` для любого рода анимаций. Оно куда приятнее и по производительности лучше. Так же стоит не забывать про семантику и размещать картинки в HTML разметке.
Код становится в разы чище и понятнее, если не нагромождать его чем попало.

```js
function switchImage(sliderSelector) {
  var images = $(sliderSelector).find('.slider__image'); // берем все картины из специфичного слайдера
  var currentImage = images.filter('.slider__image_shown'); // фильтруем для нахождения текущего показанного
  var nextImage = currentImage.next(); // берем следующую картину
  if (nextImage.length === 0) { // если она последняя, то следующего элемента не будет
    nextImage = images.first(); // поэтому в этом случае берем первую
  }
  currentImage.removeClass('slider__image_shown'); // скрываем текущую картину
  nextImage.addClass('slider__image_shown'); // показываем следующую картину
}

$(function() {
  setInterval(function () {
    switchImage('#mainSlider');
  }, 4000);
});
```

```css
.slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 220px;
  height: 160px;
}

.slider__image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: opacity 1.3s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.slider__image_shown {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainSlider" class="slider">
  <img class="slider__image slider__image_shown" src="http://wp.widewallpapers.ru/2k/nature/forest/1920x1200/forest-wallpaper-1920x1200-004.jpg">
  <img class="slider__image" src="http://anywalls.com/pic/201210/1366x768/anywalls.com-14971.jpg">
  <img class="slider__image" src="http://www.1366x768.ru/nature/29/park-wallpaper-1366x768.jpg">
  <img class="slider__image" src="http://wp.widewallpapers.ru/2k/nature/forest/1920x1080/forest-wallpaper-1920x1080-003.jpg">
</div>
```

Пользуясь `background-image` свойством так же не составит труда сделать цивильный слайдер, включая рандомный показ:

```js
function randomSwitchImage(sliderSelector) {
  var images = $(sliderSelector).find('.slider__image');
  var nextImageIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
  console.log("Show image #" + nextImageIndex);
  var nextImage = $(images[nextImageIndex]);
  
  images.removeClass('slider__image_shown');
  nextImage.addClass('slider__image_shown');
}

$(function() {
  setInterval(function () {
    randomSwitchImage('#mainSlider');
  }, 4000);
});
```

```css
.slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 220px;
  height: 160px;
}

.slider__image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: opacity 1.3s;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}

.slider__image_shown {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider__image_num_0 {
  background-image: url(http://wp.widewallpapers.ru/2k/nature/forest/1920x1200/forest-wallpaper-1920x1200-004.jpg);
}
.slider__image_num_1 {
  background-image: url(http://anywalls.com/pic/201210/1366x768/anywalls.com-14971.jpg);
}
.slider__image_num_2 {
  background-image: url(http://www.1366x768.ru/nature/29/park-wallpaper-1366x768.jpg);
}
.slider__image_num_3 {
  background-image: url(http://wp.widewallpapers.ru/2k/nature/forest/1920x1080/forest-wallpaper-1920x1080-003.jpg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainSlider" class="slider">
  <div class="slider__image slider__image_num_0 slider__image_shown" src=""></div>
  <div class="slider__image slider__image_num_1"></div>
  <div class="slider__image slider__image_num_2"></div>
  <div class="slider__image slider__image_num_3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, ваш вариант несомненно будет полезным во многих ситуациях. Но в моем случае (согласно вопроса) необходимо было использовать картинку именно в качестве `background-image` (для того чтобы в последующем была возможность применить к фону свойство `background-attachment: fixed;` ). А так - да, для других задач отличное решение! @Razmik Galstyan выше дал отличный вариант для фоновых картинок, но не хватало плавности для первой картинки и рандомности картинок при загрузке страницы поэтому поиски привили к этому варианту https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/728761/232533

Comment: @Slava рандом без говнокода готов :)

Comment: Спасибо за ваш вариант, работает как часы! Не удавалось не где найти подходящее решение, стоило на stackoverflow поинтересоваться - кучу вариантов накидали на все случаи жизни! )) Отличное сообщество и участники! Респект вам и еще раз спасибо!