# mouseover/out jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
<a class="image" href="javascript:void(0)">
   <img src="img/address.png" alt="" onmouseover="this.src='img/address-hover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='img/address.png'">
</a>
```

Первый раз столкнулся с mouseover/out. Не знаю как переписать на jQuery и добавить плавности смены картинок.

Comment: Может хотите подобное? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/728686/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C/728694?noredirect=1#comment1104455_728694

Comment: нет, это не то, что нужно. Там background, у меня совсем другое.

Comment: а плавность то какое тебе нужно?

Comment: нужно чтобы картинка менялась при наведении. За это отвечает onmouseover/out. Только вот эта смена происходит резко.

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой пример, с анимацией:

```js
var src1 = 'http://wp.widewallpapers.ru/2k/nature/forest/1920x1200/forest-wallpaper-1920x1200-004.jpg';
var src2 = 'http://anywalls.com/pic/201210/1366x768/anywalls.com-14971.jpg';
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.anim_img').bind('mouseover',function(){
    $(this).animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, 500, function() {
      $(this).attr('src',src2);
      $(this).animate({
        opacity: 1
      }, 500);
    });
  });
  $('.anim_img').bind('mouseout',function(){
    $(this).animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, 500, function() {
      $(this).attr('src',src1);
      $(this).animate({
        opacity: 1
      }, 500);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.anim_img{
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="image" href="javascript:void(0)">
   <img class="anim_img" src="http://wp.widewallpapers.ru/2k/nature/forest/1920x1200/forest-wallpaper-1920x1200-004.jpg" alt="">
</a>
```

Вот вариант второй анимация `css`:

```css
.anim_img{
  max-width: 150px;
  height: auto;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-filter: grayscale(0%);
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-filter: grayscale(0%);
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}
.anim_img:hover{
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-filter: grayscale(100%); 
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-filter: grayscale(100%); 
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<a class="image" href="javascript:void(0)">
   <img class="anim_img" src="http://wp.widewallpapers.ru/2k/nature/forest/1920x1200/forest-wallpaper-1920x1200-004.jpg" alt="">
</a>
```

Comment: @user270248 Так сойдет ?

Comment: да, но только затухание лишнее. Картинки, в моем случае, одинаковые, цвет только отличается. Нужно добиться эффекта, как в CSS с transition и hover

Comment: @user270248 ну тогда давайте эффект скажите конкретно какой, а то вы вопрос плохо вообще сформулировали

Comment: @user270248 и если картинки одинаковые то вообще не нужно на js, и нет смысла менять картинки, лишний контент для сайта, который должен грузится , надо сделать с помощью css.

Comment: картинки менять смысл есть. В моем случает это иконки почты, адреса, телефона. Нужно добиться hover эффекта, но для тега img, hover будет работать не правильно, так как это не background

Comment: @user270248 как `background`? у вас же вроде в вопросе тег `img`

Comment: да все правильно, я просто упомянул background, потому что hover с ним работает корректно. Нужен такой же результат, но только с тегом img

Comment: @user270248 обновил ответ, смотрите

Comment: даааа....спасибо...именно так и нужно

Comment: @user270248 Не за что, но только в следующий раз постарайтесь сформировать вопрос так что бы было понятно что вы хотите.

Comment: хорошо, обязательно учту

Comment: @user270248 И еще если вопрос решен то поставьте птичку в ответе.